# Take input from searchbox not in automplete list on enter button

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How can I save value not in autocomplete list?

```js
$("#tags").keyup(function(event) {
  $("#tags").click(function(){
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      ui.item.value =$("#tags").val('');
      return true;
    }
    else{
      lang = ui.item.value;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add more explanation, as it stands right now, this code is going to be extremely buggy, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: i'm trying to take user input not present in autocomplete list of search box and store it in variable called lang.